# Does there exist two different valuation $\nu_Y,\mu_Y$ such that $\mathcal O_{\eta,X}$ are both the discrete valuation rings of $\nu_Y$ and $\mu_Y$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\textbf{Definition.}$ We say a scheme $X$ is regular in codimension one if every local ring $\mathcal O_x$ of $X$ of dimension one is regular.

$(\ast)$ $X$ is a noetherian integral separated scheme which is regular in codimansion one.

Let $X$ satisfy $(\ast)$. A prime divisor on $X$ is a closed integral subscheme $Y$ of codimension one. If $Y$ is a prime divisor on $X$, let $\eta\in Y$ be its generic point. Then the local ring $\mathcal O_{\eta,X}$ is a discrete valuation ring with quotient field $K$, the function field of $X$. We call the corresponding discrete valuation $\nu_Y$ the valuation of $Y$.

My question: does there exist two different valuation $\nu_Y,\mu_Y: K^\ast\to \Bbb Z$ such that $\mathcal O_{\eta,X}$ are both the discrete valuation rings of $\nu_Y$ and $\mu_Y$?

If there exist two different valuations $\nu_Y,\mu_Y: K^\ast\to \Bbb Z$ such that $\mathcal O_{\eta,X}$ are both the discrete valuation rings of $\nu_Y$ and $\mu_Y$, could the situation happen that a divisor is a principal divisor    with a family of valuations $\{\nu_Y\}_Y$ but not a principal divisor with another family of valuations $\{\mu_Y\}_Y$?

Answer (score 2):

A discrete valuation ring is a local principal ideal domain which is not a field, and the valuation is given by picking a generator of the unique maximal ideal, say $\alpha$, and forming $\nu_\alpha$ given by: $\nu_\alpha(b)=n$ is the unique power such that $b\in (\alpha)^n$ and $b\notin (\alpha)^{n+1}$. Now, all generators of the maximal ideal differ multiplicatively by a unit, and it is easy to see that this means their valuations agree.

Thus, no, the valuation is unique.